# setting https_proxy environment variable in a secure way

Tags: bash, environment-variables, password-protection, http-proxy

The following is the standard way suggested to set the environment variable for the `https_proxy`:

`export https_proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>`

But it clearly shows/stores my password in plain-text. Even if I wrote a script that will read the password by not echoing it on the screen, the password gets stored in plain-text and when I type the command: `printenv`, it clearly shows.

Is there any way so that I need not have to store the password in the environment variable and still be able to use `wget` or other internet programs?

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/708355/is-it-safe-to-store-critical-passwords-in-server-environment-variables).